# What's the best way to set timezone for docker-compose app version 3?

Tags: docker, timezone, docker-compose

Here is my docker-compose file, how do I make `mysql`, `mongo` and `scraper` services respect my local machine TZ or a specific TZ? Do I have to configure each service differently based on how they are setup? As you can see, I tried to setup `scraper` using environment variable but how do I do it for mysql service and make sure mysql database respect that TZ?

```
version: '3.7'

services:
 mysql:
   image: mysql:8
   command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
   volumes:
     - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
     - ./:/home
   ports:
    - "3306:3306"
   environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxxx
 mongo:
   image: mongo:3
   volumes:
     - mongo-data:/data/db
     - ./:/home
   ports:
     - "27017:27017"
   environment:
     - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
 scraper:
   image: ycshao/freedom_freedom
   depends_on:
     - mysql
     - mongo
   volumes:
     - ./:/app
   environment:
     - TZ=America/New_York
   command: bash -c "ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && ./scripts/wait-for-resource-ready.sh && python main.py Scraper"
volumes:
  mysql-data:
    external:
      name: freedom-mysql-data-volume
  mongo-data:
    external:
      name: freedom-mongo-data-volume
```

Answer (score 1):

Mount the timezone of host machine to container in compose file could do the trick. But you need to set it service by service.

```
volumes:
    - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
    - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
```

Comment: Hmm this is os specific. I'm really looking for a solution cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a very good way to make it ignostic to host and guest machines. So I end up just doing command to set TZ to each guest machine. It's better than mounting volumes to map to host machine because at least it's host machine ignostic.